# Can I use NSViewController to provide a reusable NSTableView with defined columns and data?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

I'm fairly new to Xcode and Cocoa development, so please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology.

I have a window which has an NSTableView bound to a NSArrayController. The NSTableView has some predefined columns and the NSArrayController is populated with data when my window is loaded.

This all works fine, but I now need to re-use the functionality in a number of other windows. 
 After much reading I think and NSViewController is what I need, to provide an object that I can re-use in different windows in multiple .xib.

So what I have done is created a new NSViewController sub class in Xcode which also created a new xib for that controller.

The xib contains a custom view, where I have placed my NSTableView.

```
@interface KeyViewController : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *keyTable;

@end
```

The files owner class is set to the KeyViewController, and the view outlet is set to the files owner.

I then placed a ViewController object into the original window and hooked up the view to a new custom view in the window

I then set the nib name for the ViewController in its properties.

The new view never gets displayed and the view controller initWithNibName never gets called.

Am I missing something vital or missing the plot completely. Should you be able to do this just with interface builder or do I need to alloc and init the view in code?

If I do have to do it in code, whats the purpose of the ViewController object in IB and the Nib Name property for it?

Thanks..